# Solgema.fullcalendar AJAX throws error

Tags: ajax, plone, fullcalendar

### Overview

I am running a Plone 4.2.4 server, it is a standalone install and doesn't have any add-ons installed other than `Solgema.fullcalendar`. Everything installed a-ok (I can see nothing in my buildout output regarding errors or missing dependencies and running my instance in foreground mode shows no problems).

### Buildout

Inside of my buildout I have: (as they request on [this link](http://plone.org/products/solgema.fullcalendar))

```
eggs = 
    [...]
    Solgema.fullcalendar

zcml = 
    [...]
    Solgema.fullcalendar
```

### Process

I followed the instructions in the documentation, going to <kbd>Add New...</kbd> > <kbd>Collection</kbd>

Then on my collection selecting <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Solgema Fullcalendar</kbd>

I leave the Calendar Properties tab alone and besides changing the view to `Month' everything else remains the same.

### Problem

When clicking on a blank date block, I see a little spinner.gif signifying something is loading, but in my Javascript console I see:

```
Error: uncaught exception: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; 
attempted to call method 'destroy'
```

This happens via the right click menu also, the right click menu loads but throws the above error once I click any of the buttons contained in it.

I can drag events, and resize them without any problems (however I think something is missing as after either dragging or resizing the event, the browser takes me to the page for that event).

### Summary

It seems like I'm missing a Javascript file that was not included in `Solgema.fullcalendar` however I have no idea what script it was and I am unable to decipher this Javascript error (above).

If anyone has any experience with this, ideas or  your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: file a bug report at: http://plone.org/products/solgema.fullcalendar/issues

Comment: For the records: http://plone.org/products/solgema.fullcalendar/issues/58